# MemberNotNullWhen (or other code analysis attributes) for inherited members?

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have a class:

```
public abstract class InvestorAccount
{
    public bool IsRegistered => ...;
}
```

And a subclass:

```
public class PrivateInvestorAccount : InvestorAccount
{
    public Person? Holder { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to teach the compiler that `Holder` is not null when `IsRegistered` is `true`.

If both props were declared in the same class if could just annotate `IsRegistered` with `[MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(Holder))]`. However, in the inheritance scenario, applying
`[MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(PrivateInvestorAccount.Holder))]` ends up in a compilation error:

> error CS8776: Member 'Holder' cannot be used in this attribute.

Is there any way of telling the compiler that `Holder` is not `null` in this scenario?

Answer (score 7):

You can define `IsRegistered` as virtual...

```
public abstract class InvestorAccount
{
    public virtual bool IsRegistered => ...;
}
```

...and then override it in your subclass...

```
public class PrivateInvestorAccount : InvestorAccount
{
    public override bool IsRegistered => base.IsRegistered;
    public Person? Holder { get; set; }
}
```

...which allows you to place an attribute on it *only in the subclass* (which makes sense, because `Holder`, and, thus, the additional *meaning* of your `IsRegistered` property, is only available in your subclass):

```
public class PrivateInvestorAccount : InvestorAccount
{
    [MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(Holder))]
    public override bool IsRegistered => base.IsRegistered;
    public Person? Holder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sure. A possible work around.

Comment: @Dejan: I'm afraid it's the best we are going to get (but, of course, I'm always glad to be proven wrong). If you think about it, it also makes sense on a conceptual level: The base class `InvestorAccount` is not supposed to know anything about properties of its subclasses (e.g. `Holder`): Subclasses have a dependency on the base class, not the other way around. Thus, the information that `IsRegistered` influences `Holder` *should* be in the subclass, not in the base class.

Comment: Actually, even this approach is problematic, as I cannot do a `if (acc.IsRegistered) ...` and expect the compiler to know anything about the nullability of `Holder` *if* `acc` is an `InvestorAccount` (and not a `PrivateInvestorAccount`).

Comment: @Dejan: True, but if `acc` is an `InvestorAccount`, there *is no `Holder` property*, so the problem is moot.

Comment: I really appreciate your comments and I think you totally have a valid point here in regards to OOP. However, pragmatically speaking, my code first check some stuff on the superclass (`if !acc.Registered return`) and then continues with handling specific subtypes (e.g. get the `Holder` of a private investor account). And it'd be brilliant to not having to use `!` on `Holder` since I know it's not null.

Comment: @Dejan: Indeed, that would be great. Unfortunately, I can't think of a good solution for that. I even tried moving `Holder` into the base class (which would be an option if all of your subclasses had a Holder, just of different types), but even then C# doesn't recognize that the not-null-when information is still valid for the subclass: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nhY9EX

Answer (score 1):

> If both props were declared in the same class

They are in the same class, you're deriving there. So the syntax is as you said:

```
[MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(Holder))]
```

Also, `nameof` is syntactic sugar (more or less) for the word after it, in this case the above is equivalent, yet strictly better, to:

```
[MemberNotNullWhen(true, "Holder")]
```

Comment: I don't think this is actually working. As I said, I get a `warning CS8776: Member 'Holder' cannot be used in this attribute.` (if you don't configure warnings as errors). And trying it out like: `var acc = new PrivateInvestorAccount(); if (acc.IsRegistered) acc.Holder.ToString();` leads to `warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference.`

Comment: I think you got it backwards: Yes, in the derived class, they are both in the same class, but OP wants to put the attribute on `IsRegistered`, which is (only) defined in the base class.